# How to show background jobs in shell hidden by &

Tags: shell, makefile, init, ampersand

I run a webserver by one `Makefile` by command `make install`

The content of `Makefile` is

```
project : webserver.c

webserver.c : server/webserver.c
    gcc -g  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -frecord-gcc-switches -fno-stack-protector -g  -o server/webserver -lpthread  -lnsl -lresolv -D_TS_ERRNO server/webserver.c
install :
    sudo /etc/init.d/fhttpd.init stop
    sudo cp server/webserver /usr/local/fhttpd/fhttpd
    sudo chmod 4755 /usr/local/fhttpd/fhttpd
    sudo /etc/init.d/fhttpd.init start

clean : 
    rm server/webserver
```

the content of fhttpd.init is

```
httpd="/usr/local/fhttpd/fhttpd"
prog=fhttpd
port=8080
RETVAL=0

# disable ASLR so that lab exercise will work reliably
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

start() {
                echo "Stopping $prog..."
                killall $prog
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        $httpd $port &
}
stop() {
        echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
        killall $prog
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  restart)
        start
        ;;
  reload)
          start
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $prog {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

I guess init use `&` to make server run in background. But after I use that command. I used `jobs` command to show all my jobs, I can't see anything. But if I run it directly, like this

```
lhu343ai@server:~$ /usr/local/fhttpd/fhttpd 8080 &
[1] 7154
lhu343ai@server:~$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 /usr/local/fhttpd/fhttpd 8080 &
```

Everything is OK to me.

If I just use `make install` or `sudo /etc/init.d/fhttpd.init start`, `jobs` shows nothing. In fact, the server is running correctly. I just don't know how does it work because I use `&` in /etc/init.d/fhttpd.init.

I don't know why is the reason I can't use 'jobs' with `makefile`. And how can I get background program back in this case.

Comment: The init script runs in a different shell, so its jobs won't be visible in your shell. You'll want to use a different tool, like `pgrep`, to verify the server is running.

Comment: Do you know if I want to see the state of it, how to switch ?

Comment: You cannot access the shell that launched the server. It's not running anymore. I would expect that `fhttpd status` would do something

Comment: Thanks, this is a project to let us use someway to crash the server. How can I see if it crashes?

Comment: Try reading the server logs

Comment: This is one self write code. Not about apache and may not have log. I just want to see the status of webserver program.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect this command to elevate execution to the superuser's userspace:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/fhttpd.init start
```

As a result you wouldn't see that process in your regular user, `lhu343ai`. You'd want to check the `jobs` for the superuser, instead. For example, `sudo jobs` would be the command you're looking for...

Please note that *this isn't a programming question*, and it certainly isn't about C. We have enough *low-level noise* spammed over that tag from people confusing x86 assembly concepts with C, as it is.